# Football betting game - point calculation

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm creating a football betting game in PHP/MSQL and right now im trying to calculate the scoring system with if-statements.

the bets are saved per team like this:

```
Team 1: Bayern Munich  
Team 2: Borussia Dortmund

Bet_Team1: 4  
Bet_Team2: 1
```

The actual results:
Bayern Munich  **5:2**  Borussia Dortmund

saved like this:

```
Result_Team1: 5
Result_Team2: 2
```

I tried this with if statements:

```
// Completely right draw:    
if($Bet_Team1 === $Result_Team1 && $Bet_Team2 == $Result_Team2){
    $points = $points+6; }
```

It works well, but i don't know how to calculate the points, if the user bets the right winner team like in the example above with Bayern Munich and Borussia Dortmund.

Comment: They bet 4-1 but result was 5-2 So they are not `===` or even `==`

Comment: hey, the if-statement is just an example for calculating a draw game.

Comment: Can you please explain what isn't working?

Comment: Well all you need to do is build another if, it will be more complex, but have a go and then we have a better idea what you actually want to do

Comment: @fislerdata It not that its not working, he just cannot see how to write the next IF statement. _So its a code it for me question really_

Comment: i don't now how to calculate the points, if the user bets the right winner team . Bet: 4:1 Result 5:2. I tried `code $TippT1 > $TippT4 && $ET1 > $ET4` but this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this to get you started

```
// Completely right draw:    
if($Bet_Team1 === $Result_Team1 && $Bet_Team2 == $Result_Team2){
    $points = $points+6; 
}
// they guessed the winning team but wrong score
else if ( ($Result_Team1 > $Result_Team2 && $Bet_Team1 > $Bet_Team2) ||
          ($Result_Team2 > $Result_Team1 && $Bet_Team2 > $Bet_Team1)
        ) 
{
    $points += ?  // how many points do you allocate to this situation
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Comment: A nice implementation of this in php7 would be to use the [spaceship operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778). Something like: `if(($bet_team1 <=> $bet_team2) == ($result_team1 <=> $result_team2)){ // add points }` This will also account for incorrect scores on draws.